# Error with sum() in MySQL running on Google Colab

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

I have a CSV file with 9994 records and 21 fields of which 4 are numeric, stored in Google Drive.
I install MySQL inside a Google Colab VM. The install has what seems to be minor error but MySQL starts and SQL commands work correctly

```
Error: Unable to shut down server with process id 1276
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.47) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.2) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ideep4py/lib/libmkldnn.so.0 is not a symbolic link

Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I download the CSV file into the Colab VM, Then I created a table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ss_order (\
RowID int(4),\
OrderID char(14),OrderDate date,\
ShipDate date,ShipMode varchar(16),\
CustomerID char(8),CustomerName varchar(30),Segment varchar(20),\
Country varchar(30),City varchar(30),State varchar(30),PostalCode char(5),Region varchar(15) ,\
ProductID varchar(20), Category varchar(40), SubCategory varchar(40), ProductName varchar(200), \
Sales decimal(8,2), Quantity int(4), Discount decimal(4,2), Profit decimal(8,2) \
); \
```

Then I loaded the table

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'SS_Orders.csv' INTO TABLE ss_order \
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  IGNORE 1 LINES;  \
```

No errors 
I execute a very simple SQL command

```
select count(*),sum(Sales),Sum(Quantity), Sum(Profit) from ss_order;
```

and get the following answer

```
+----------+------------+---------------+-------------+
| count(*) | sum(Sales) | Sum(Quantity) | Sum(Profit) |
+----------+------------+---------------+-------------+
|     9994 | 2026591.44 |        382386 |   276351.97 |
+----------+------------+---------------+-------------+
```

I subsequently read the CSV file into a Pandas Dataframe and generate the same sums as follows

```
dfSS['Quantity'].sum()
37873
dfSS['Sales'].sum()
2297200.8603
dfSS['Profit'].sum()
286397.0217
```

Obviously these is a huge difference between the sum generated by MySQL and that generated by Python Pandas. I have checked with Google Sheets and MS Excel that the Python Pandas answer is correct, or at least agrees with Excel and Sheets sum function. 
The Colab Notebook with the code -- both MySQL and Pandas -- is available at [this URL](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Sp7ZFvWGHhSqYR_zGpDvXQQqdHMqhVyJ?usp=sharing). The URL of the data CSV file is available within the Colab Notebook. 
Where is my mistake? or error?

Comment: One possible reason could be the presence of COMMAS in some parts of the data. Some text fields have comma in the data. These fields are surrounded by double quotes. So the Python read_csv command is able to keep this data together, but the MySQL load command is unable keep the comma within the previous field.

Comment: The real challenge is to use the LOAD command in a manner that can handle a piece of data like "some text, some more text" as ONE field and NOT two fields.

Answer (score 0):

The LOAD command must be changed as follows

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'SS_Orders.csv' INTO TABLE ss_order \
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' enclosed by '\"' IGNORE 1 LINES;  \
```

to reflect the fact that field data is enclosed by " 
This solves the problem completely.